# How to separate filename from path in python (PyQt4.QtCore.QString)

Tags: python, pyqt4

How to separate filename from path using Python?

I'm using `PyQt4` and my String is not Python String but, `PyQt4.QtCore.QString`

I can do it like:

```
filename=my_path.split("/")[-1]
```

But I think separator is OS specific, also I can't use something like `os.path.basename` because it only work for original python string, so what will be the best option to do it?

Comment: Repeated question
Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384737/python-extract-file-name-from-path-no-matter-what-the-os-path-format

Comment: @PrakharAgrawal this question about path stored as basic python string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the `QString` to a Python `str` before use. For example:

```
filename_str = unicode(my_path)
```

...and then use standard Python `os` functions to get the filename:

```
os.path.basename(filename_str)
```

Or, in a single step:

```
os.path.basename(unicode(my_path))
```

Note you can avoid this problem altogether by using the [newer PyQt4 API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238193/pyqt-new-api-with-python-2), or alternatively using PyQt5. With these updates PyQt functions return native Python strings (and other variables) where possible so you can work with them without converting. It makes things a lot simpler.

Comment: Always use `unicode` to convert `QString`, so as to avoid encoding errors with non-ascii characters.