# PyQt4: Saving list to QSettings

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I made an list (array) that would count number of game finish. But if someone restarted game, length of list would reset.

As I know QSettings is dedicated to save and store data. I have read documentation but didn't help me enough.

For example I have a global array:

```
global finishcount
finishcount = []
```

How can I apply this to QSettings? So then I can append data on it without data loss after restart.

Should it look something like this?

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
global finishcount
finishcount = []
settings = QtCore.QSettings(self)
settings.setValue(finishcount, self)
```

How can I achieve this? Or can I make list in QSettings itself where I can append something?

Comment: Save the settings in the `closeEvent` of the main window, and read the settings in `__init__`.

Answer (score 3):

Below is a very simple demo that shows how to read and write a list of integers to `QSettings`. The demo automatically adds a new value every time the window is opened and closed.

If you're using PyQt, there is no need to use `json` at all. For lists, just provide a default, and specify the type of the contained values:

```
    settings.value('finishcount', [], int)
```

Demo:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        settings = QtCore.QSettings('my_org', 'my_app')
        self._finishcount = settings.value('finishcount', [], int)
        print('read settings: %s' % self._finishcount)
        # add a new value for testing
        self._finishcount.append(len(self._finishcount))

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        settings = QtCore.QSettings('my_org', 'my_app')
        settings.setValue('finishcount', self._finishcount)
        print('save settings: %s' % self._finishcount)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 100, 100)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**NB**: for the special case of a list of strings, it's best to use this:

```
    settings.value('finishcount', [], 'QStringList')
```

rather than specifying the type with `str`. Otherwise, empty lists don't get treated properly.

Comment: I found that after setting `settings.setValue('mykey',[])`, on the NEXT load of the program `settings.value('mykey', [], str)` gives `''` instead of `[]`. Is it to be expected?

Comment: @Jason Yeah, I think this is a bit of a wart. You can work around it by doing: `settings.value('mykey', [], 'QStringList')`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally it looks something like this.  This also assumes your using the `v2` version of the `QVariant` api; otherwise, the results returned from `QSettings.value` is going to be a `QVariant` and you'll need to cast it to the appropriate python type.  If you're using a recent version of `PyQt` then you should be on `v2`, [but if not you can force it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6238226/1547004) by sticking this at the top of your file

```
import sip
sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)
sip.setapi('QString', 2)
```

Also, even with the `v2` version of the api, it often doesn't always work as expected with anything more complicated than strings or numbers.  For more complex types like `lists` and `dicts`, I've found it's often better to serialize the values using [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) or [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) and save that to the `QSettings` instead, and then unserialize it myself when retrieving it.

```
import json

class MyWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.myvalue = 10
        self.mylist = [1,2,3]
        self.restoreSettings()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.saveSettings()
        super(MyWidget, self).closeEvent(event)

    def saveSettings(self):
        settings = QSettings('myorg', 'myapp')
        settings.setValue('myvalue', self.myvalue)
        settings.setValue('mylist', json.dumps(self.mylist))

    def restoreSettings(self):
        settings = QSettings('myorg', 'myapp')
        self.myvalue = settings.value('myvalue', self.myvalue)
        try:
            self.mylist = json.loads(settings.value('mylist', None))
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            pass
```

Comment: Can you give a specific example of a `list` or `dict` that doesn't work as expected? Given the fact that `json` only supports a limited range of types, it would be a bug if they couldn't also be serialized by `QSettings`.

Comment: Admittedly, I'm using PySide -- but `[1,2,3]` is returned as `[u'1', u'2', u'3']` from `QSettings`

Comment: Ah. PyQt has added an argument that allows you to specify the type. So `settings.value('mylist', type=int)` will return the right thing. Don't think PySide supports that, but you can work around the issue by putting the list inside a `tuple`. Or, more generally, just force Qt to write a `@Variant` entry, rather than a string-list.

Comment: I don't quite understand second code, Do i need to make a json file where i will have my lists? if so, how can i achieve that since i am not familiar with json files.

Comment: It's basically just converting your list to a string before it saves it.  And then it converts it from a string back into a list when it reads it.